# MySQL 8.0 Performance on large datasets

Tags: mysql, performance, select

I have a simple schema bellow with multiple entries and I would like to speed up the queries. I have included indexes but they didn't had a major impact on performance but I don't have experience in handling big data in mysql. It is running on a local MySQL 8.0 server on a Windows 10 with 16GB RAM.

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `drugs`;
    /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
    /*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
    CREATE TABLE `drugs` (
      `drug_id` int NOT NULL,
      `ATC` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`drug_id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `drug_id_UNIQUE` (`drug_id`),
      KEY `drug_ATC` (`ATC`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
    
--
-- Table structure for table `events`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `events`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `event_id` int NOT NULL,
  `Meddra` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `event_id_UNIQUE` (`event_id`,`Meddra`),
  KEY `event_Meddra` (`Meddra`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Table structure for table `reports`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `reports`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `reports` (
  `report_id` int NOT NULL,
  `reportDate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`report_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `report_id_UNIQUE` (`report_id`),
  KEY `reportDateIndex` (`reportDate`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Table structure for table `reports_drugs`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `reports_drugs`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `reports_drugs` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `report_id_FK` int NOT NULL,
  `drug_id_FK` int NOT NULL,
  `type` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  KEY `report_id_fk_idx` (`report_id_FK`),
  KEY `report_id_fk_idx1` (`drug_id_FK`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  CONSTRAINT `drug_report_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`drug_id_FK`) REFERENCES `drugs` (`drug_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `report_drug_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`report_id_FK`) REFERENCES `reports` (`report_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=143260638 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Table structure for table `reports_events`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `reports_events`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `reports_events` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `report_id_FK` int NOT NULL,
  `events_id_FK` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  KEY `report_event_id_fk_idx` (`report_id_FK`),
  KEY `event_report_id_fk_idx` (`events_id_FK`),
  CONSTRAINT `event_report_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`events_id_FK`) REFERENCES `events` (`event_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `report_event_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`report_id_FK`) REFERENCES `reports` (`report_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=143258062 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My artificial data consists of 30.000.000 entries at the `reports` table. Each report has a median value of drugs and events of 5, meaning that the `reports_drugs` and `reports_events` tables have roughly 150.000.000 entries each.

Two of the queries that are being used and their response time.

```
SELECT report_id,reportDate,Meddra FROM events
INNER JOIN reports_events ON events.event_id=reports_events.events_id_FK
INNER JOIN reports ON reports_events.report_id_FK=reports.report_id
WHERE Meddra=11125127;
```

0.36 sec duration / 37.625 sec fetch

```
SELECT report_id,reportDate,Meddra,ATC,type FROM events
INNER JOIN reports_events ON events.event_id=reports_events.events_id_FK
INNER JOIN reports ON reports_events.report_id_FK=reports.report_id
INNER JOIN reports_drugs ON reports.report_id=reports_drugs.report_id_FK
INNER JOIN drugs ON reports_drugs.drug_id_FK=drugs.drug_id
WHERE Meddra=11125127 AND ATC="ACNKMFRRMVST";
```

80.296 sec duration / 0 sec fetch

Both of those experience a bottleneck during the 'executing' phase

| Query | Status | Duration | Source_function | Source_file | Source_line |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1st Query |  | 'executing' | '37.614281' | 'SELECT_LEX_UNIT::ExecuteIterat' | 'sql_union.cc' |
| 2nd Query |  | 'executing' | '80.293151' | 'SELECT_LEX_UNIT::ExecuteIterat' | 'sql_union.cc' |

Are those times to be expected with such a large dataset or the performance can be increased somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Please qualify all columns it makes it easier for us to help you:

```
SELECT  r.report_id, r.reportDate, e.Meddra
    FROM  events AS e
    INNER JOIN  reports_events AS e AS re  ON e.event_id=re.events_id_FK
    INNER JOIN  reports AS r  ON re.report_id_FK=r.report_id
    WHERE  e.Meddra=11125127;

SELECT  r.report_id, r.reportDate, e.Meddra, d.ATC, rd.type
    FROM  events AS e
    INNER JOIN  reports_events AS e AS re  ON e.event_id = re.events_id_FK
    INNER JOIN  reports AS r  ON re.report_id_FK=r.report_id
    INNER JOIN  reports_drugs AS d AS rd  ON r.report_id = rd.report_id_FK
    INNER JOIN  drugs AS d  ON rd.drug_id_FK = d.drug_id
    WHERE  e.Meddra = 11125127
      AND  d.ATC = "ACNKMFRRMVST";
```

I assume there are other columns in the tables?

Your `UNIQUE` keys are redundant and should be Dropped.  (A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` key.)

Many-to-many tables should be indexed in a better way.  See discussion here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table
That, alone, may solve the performance questions.

The second query will step through the 5 tables in one of these ways:

```
e -> re -> r -> rd -> d
         --OR--
d -> rd -> r -> re -> e
```

The link provides the optimal indexes to allow either to work optimally (namely composite indexes, or the equivalent by knowing how InnoDB handles the PK).

And, since there is a test on `e.Meddra` and `e.DTC`, the Optimizer will make a semi-intellengent choice of which to start with.